# How to calculate "amountOutMin" on some DEX-es?

Tags: uniswap, exchanges, decentralized-exchange, layer-2

There's a function  in a contract  on HOT-protocol exchange

```
sendToL2( uint256 chainId, address recipient, uint256 amount, uint256 amountOutMin, uint256 deadline, address relayer, uint256 relayerFee )
```

Instance:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x914f986a44acb623a277d6bd17368171fcbe4273#code

However, it also exists in `IUniswapV2Router02.sol` which means that it's originally from it.

At https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02 it says:

> The minimum amount of out put tokens that must be received for the transaction not to revert.

How precisely does one calculate `amountOutMin`? To then be able to pass into a function.

Comment: It is for [slippage protection](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/slippage). [You can find some calculation examples here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/aba3c985e645bfdf9d723f1837d68c0ee4014a07/eth_defi/uniswap_v2/swap.py#L12).

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I'm asking how to calculate it

Comment: I linked an example with calculations, as I do not have time to type it out, and I am not working for Hot protocl support. I suggest you contact Hot protocol directly.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa are  you working in the support of Stackexchange then?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa now I've noticied the "calculation examples" part. Cheers